# Derefence hash of hash variable

Tags: perl

How do I dereference such a variable to get '99' and 'Problem in Parameter' ?

```
  DB<103> print Dumper($error_code);
  $VAR1 = \{
            '99' => 'Problem in Parameter'
          };


  DB<104> x $error_code
  0  REF(0x30393f34)
   -> HASH(0x30393ea4)
         99 => 'Problem in Parameter'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
my ($key, $value) = each %$$error_code;
say $key;
say $value;
```

**output:**

```
99
Problem in Parameter
```

Comment: Have you tested it? There is a typo (`my` should be lower case) and a runtime error, too.

Comment: Note: Using `each` that way will leave the hash iterator in the middle of the hash, breaking any later use of `each`. Just get rid of the word `each` and the problem is entirely avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You have a reference to a reference. You have to double dereference, first as scalar, than as hash:

```
my $error_code = \{
  '99' => 'Problem in Parameter'
};
my ($ninety_nine) = keys %$$error_code;
my $string        = ${$error_code}->{$ninety_nine};
print "$ninety_nine, $string\n";
```

Comment: Note: Using `each` that way will leave the hash iterator in the middle of the hash, breaking any later use of `each`. Just get rid of the word `each` and the problem is entirely avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You have a reference to a reference to a hash. So you need two dereferences.

```
$error_code    A reference to a reference to a hash
$$error_code   A reference to a hash
%$$error_code  A hash
```

So,

```
my ($key, $value) = %$$error_code;
say $key;
say $value;
```